# Is it possible to put a readme file for R code on github, that displays output?

Tags: r, github, markdown, r-markdown

Recently I participated in the ***#100daysofmlcode*** challenge on Linkedin, started by Siraj Raval. I do all of my coding in R. But when I push an RMarkdown file or readme file for my rcode, on Github, it doesn't show the output generated from the code. This makes it really difficult for viewers to catch up with the explanation. Is there a way we could display the code and output, so that it becomes easier for readers to understand? I know they can pull the changes I make from github and see them on their local machines. But considering the time limitations that everyone has, I would still like to know if there is a way we can display both Rcode and output in a readme file on github.

Thank you

Comment: In your yaml, instead of `output: html_document` use `output: github_document`. When you knit, you'll get a [github-flavored markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown) document.

Comment: Or even better, give `blogdown` a try, build your own blog and host it on githup page or netlify.

Comment: [Here is a live example repo](https://github.com/tcgriffith/supreadme)

Comment: Thank you Camille I tried your way as well, but when I pushed the changes up to my github repo, they still didn't display the output, but if you use `output: rmarkdown::github_document` then it worked. Not sure why, but still thanks. And TC Zhang, I am thinking of setting up my own blow, so, I will definitely try your suggestion. Really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is just a server, it can't process your Rmarkdown file. Two strategies are:

1. Call your file `README.Rmd`, and run `render()` on it to generate a `README.md` file that contains the output and push both to GitHub.
2. Setup a continuous integration service like [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) and instruct it to render your README and push the result back to GitHub.

The first option is easiest from a technical setup perspective - you just have to `render()`.

The second option is more convenient but requires some setup in your repo, configuring Travis to build (but not build on its own commits), and setting up credentials on Travis to do the push back to GitHub. To do this you'll need a `.travis.yml` file that looks something like:

```
language: r
script:
  - bash renderreadme.sh
```

And a bash script file in your repo called `renderreadme.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o nounset
renderreadme(){
  ## Set up Repo parameters
  git init
  git config user.name "your_github_username"
  git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
  git config --global push.default simple

  ## Get drat repo
  git remote add upstream "https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG.git"
  git fetch upstream
  git checkout master

  Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("README.Rmd")'

  git add README.md
  git commit -m "knit README [skip ci]"
  git push
}
renderreadme
```

And you'll need to use [the travis client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#readme) (or something equivalent) to store the secure GitHub credentials needed for the `git push` operation in that script to succeed. The general guidance in ["Building an R Project"](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/) for Travis will be useful for these general configuration aspects.

Answer (score 0):

In markdown, you use `  ` for inline code and ``` ``` for blocks (multiple lines) of code

Comment: Hi developer. I think you misjudged my question. There is no problem while knitting the markdown file, its just that when I push the readme file on github, it just displays the code, but it doesn't display the output generated by that code.Though thanks for responding.